# Why object files generated in tmp folder?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

When I look the map file of my program, I found there are objects were generated in `/tmp` folder? like this:

```
.bss.GpuMem    0x000000007555cf00  0x2000000 /tmp/ccx8wlcD.ltrans6.ltrans.o
```

and the object file name doesn't relate to the source file which contains the symbol.

What behaviors like this?

---

What I expect:

As `GpmEem` is in file `XXX.c`, so object supposes like `XXX.o` and put it under the build folder.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: How do you compile your program?